# <LI> under <UL> width not 100% on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Once again I have an IE problem. I have a dropdown menu with `<LI>` items falling under it vertically, and the `<UL>` above has a background colour. The `<LI>` has a hover background colour so I definitely need it to fill the full width, but only on IE it does not work.

The sample I'm working on is [here](http://themes.brixwork.com/altamont/). Put your mouse over the "RESOURCES" menu item. It works well on FF but not on IE (duh).

```
#menu {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative !important;

}

#menu li a:link, #menu li a:visited {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color:#ddd;
}

#menu li a:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    color:#fff;
}

.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    display: block;
    background-color:#906117;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    top:15px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#menu li:hover .submenu {
    left: -5px;
}

.submenu li {
    text-align: left !important;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding: 3px 0px 5px 0px !important;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.submenu li:hover {
    background-color: #f79c10;
}

.submenu li a:link, .submenu li a:visited {
    color:#fff !important;
    font-size:12px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: block;
    padding:3px 7px 5px 7px !important;
    min-width: auto;
    zoom: normal;

}

.submenu li a:hover, .submenu li a:active {
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really work well in Chrome either. Please post relevant HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
#menu .submenu li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: The winning answer! The float:none seems to be the difference maker.

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left` for your `LI` and move all the other styling to your `A` tag. Add `display:block` to your `A` tag.

Remember to clear your floats after your menu.

Comment: I did end up moving the colour styles to the A tag... the only part that doesn't work is the float:left on the LI which doesn't seem to work. It had some really weird results.

Answer (score 0):

Display inline does not usually expand to the full width. Try setting it to

```
display:inline-block
```